# How to freez an element after drop in particular container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some elements which are draggable.

you can check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Neha_Maniyar/SRPm2/18/)

I want to freeze these elements after dropping into particular container. you can say that i have to drop one element into one block, it cannot be dropped to other blocks.

```
function handleDropEvent (event, ui) {
if ($(this).hasClass('occupied')) {
    ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', true);
    return false;
}
$(this).append(ui.draggable);
ui.draggable.position({of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top'});
ui.draggable.css('z-index', 0);
setTimeout(validateDropzones, 0);
}
```

Comment: where is link to check??

Comment: sorry
http://jsfiddle.net/Neha_Maniyar/SRPm2/18/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`ui.draggable('destroy')`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-destroy) in your drop handler: http://jsfiddle.net/SRPm2/41/

```
function handleDropEvent (event, ui) {
  // ...
  ui.draggable.draggable('destroy');
}
```